# Removing SectionIndex dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am using sectionIndexTitlesForTableView to display index in a UITableView. It is working fine but I am using the same TableView to display something where I do not need this index. So, the question is how to remove the sectionIndex?

Comment: Have you tried returning nil and reloading the section index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `BOOL` value to track which display you are using (the first or the second) and do something like this (`isDisplayingFirst` is a boolean):

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   if (isDisplayingFirst) {
      // return your section index titles
   } 
   return nil; // otherwise return nothing
}
```